# To call the dialogue only after making changes in the form in angular

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have an component called `add-customer` which i am displaying in an `dialogue window` after clicking an button called `add` as shown in below image.

[image]

In the `add-customer` there two buttons `1)Save` and `2)Cancel`.On clicking `cancel` i am calling an component called `delete` in another `dialogue window` as shown in below image

[image]

This scenario is working fine for, but i want to call this `delete` component in the `dialogue window` **only if i did any changes** in the `registration form` (i,e in add-customer component).How can i write conditions for this??
Here is the [stackblitz](https://angular-material2-issue-ax8st1.stackblitz.io) link

Comment: Are those reactive or template driven forms?

Comment: You might want to consider implementing routing for this and then using the `CanDeactivate` Guard when the user is leaving this form. In the Guard, you can check whether the form was dirty and then based on that, show the delete modal. Ideally you should be able to do the same thing in your `openDialog` method though.

Comment: Reactive forms. @ritaj

Comment: Well, in reactive forms you have something called 'dirty'. You can check if the form has changed by cheching the condition of `form.dirty`.

Comment: @PrashanthGH similiar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50386974/detect-if-data-in-form-was-changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `AddCustomerComponent`, in the `openDialog` method, check if the form is `dirty` and open the model only in that case. If the `addCusForm` is not `dirty` you can simply call the `closeAll` method on the `dialog` so as to close the modal directly:

```
openDialog(): void {
  if (this.addCusForm.dirty) {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DeleteComponent, {
      width: '340px',
    });
  } else {
    this.dialog.closeAll();
  }
}
```

Here's an [**Updated StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-modal-form?file=app/add-customer/add-customer.component.ts) for your ref.

Comment: This is working fine, but i want to close the `add-customer` component on clicking the `cancel` button if i didn't did any changes. How can i do this?

Comment: Yeah I've already updated the answer for the same. Please check. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to check pristine or dirty property in form.

like this..

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #myForm="ngForm">
```

in component

```
myForm.form.pristine
```