# How to check for state change in angular 4/6?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

My task is to create an account information web page which consists of 4 pre-filled fields (given name, family name, username and email) and a common save button at the bottom. User can change any field by the respective field. I want save button to be enabled only if user changes any fields. Any method to track state changes? My code is as follows:

```
 <mat-card-content>
    <div class="form-group">
      <mat-form-field class="simple-form-field-50">
        <input matInput placeholder="Given name" name="givenName" formControlName="givenName">
      </mat-form-field>
      <mat-form-field class="simple-form-field-50">
        <input matInput placeholder="Family name" name="familyName" formControlName="familyName">
      </mat-form-field>
      <br>
      <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput placeholder="Email" name="email" formControlName="email">
      </mat-form-field>
      <br>
      <button
          [disabled]="waiting"
          class="simple-form-button" 
          color="primary" 
          mat-raised-button 
          type="submit" 
          value="submit">
        Save
      </button> 
    </div>
</mat-card-content>
```

My Code Output:
[image: Code Output]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using a Reactive Form, you can use [**`valueChanges`**](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#valueChanges) on the FormGroup.

Since it is of type `Observable`, you can `subscribe` to it to set a variable of type `boolean` that will be used in the template to enable the button.

```
...

@Component({...})
export class AppComponent  {
  form: FormGroup;
  disableButton = true;

  ngOnInit() {
    ...

    this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(changes => this.disableButton = false);

  }
}
```

And in your template:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  ...
  <button [disabled]="disableButton">Submit</button>
</form>
```

---

### UPDATE:

If you want to disable it when values don't really change, check for the current value of the form with the previous value:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  form: FormGroup;
  disableButton = true;

  userValue = {
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 'Doe',
    email: 'john.doe@domain.com' 
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      firstName: new FormControl(),
      lastName: new FormControl(),
      email: new FormControl()
    });
    this.form.patchValue(this.userValue);
    this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(changes => this.wasFormChanged(changes));
  }

  private wasFormChanged(currentValue) {
    const fields = ['firstName', 'lastName', 'email'];

    for(let i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
      const fieldName = fields[i];
      if(this.userValue[fieldName] !== currentValue[fieldName]) {
        console.log('Came inside');
        this.disableButton = false;
        return;
      }
    }
    this.disableButton = true;
  }

}
```

**NOTE:** StackBlitz is updated accordingly.

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-enable-form-submit-on-change?file=src/app/app.component.html) for your ref.

Comment: Can you share a code snippet. I could not understand still.

Comment: @MadhavanSundararaj, just added a working sample stackblitz for your ref.

Comment: What if `Value` erased by user and typed again?

Comment: It's working but if i clear it and write the same value, its still enabled. Any way to check for that too? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @MadhavanSundararaj, I've updated my answer with the fix that you want. I think it should work now.

Comment: userValue returns undefined for me. Any method to rectify it?

Answer (score 2):

```js
onChange(targetValue : string ){  
console.log(targetValue );}
```

```html
<input matInput placeholder="test" name="test" formControlName="testNM" (input)="onChange($event.target.value)">
```

Answer (score 1):

This is called `Dirty Check`.

You may find this SO answer very useful:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50387044/1331040

Here is the guide for `Template-Driven Forms`
https://angular.io/guide/forms

Here is the guide for `Reactive Forms`
https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

And here is the difference between two concepts
https://blog.angular-university.io/introduction-to-angular-2-forms-template-driven-vs-model-driven/

Hope these help.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
  form: FormGroup;
  disableButton = true;
  originalObj: any;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      control: new FormControl('Value')
    });

    this.originalObj = this.form.controls['control'].value; // store the original value in one variable

    this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(changes => {
      if (this.originalObj == changes.control)  // this if added for check the same value
      {
        this.disableButton = true;
      }
      else {
        this.disableButton = false;
      }
    }
    );
}
```

[`WORKING EXAMPLE`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-enable-form-submit-on-change-jezmhc)

Comment: This works fine. What is control here? I have the following in my ts 
this.form = new FormGroup ({
            givenName: new FormControl(user.givenName),
            familyName: new FormControl(user.familyName),
            email: new FormControl(user.email),
          });

Comment: its a name of control that you want to check

Comment: if there is givenName constrol then `changes.givenName`, `changes.familyName`, `changes.email`

Comment: try to optimized as I am in hurry so unable to do this