# Dirty event fires in place of touch event

Tags: angular, internet-explorer-11

Dirty event gets fired in place of touch event when I click on the material input field. It happens in IE 11 only.

Comment: Please provide a sandbox reproducing the issue.

Comment: can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Besides, please check [this article](https://angular.io/guide/forms#track-control-state-and-validity-with-ngmodel) and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50386974/detect-if-data-in-form-was-changed). I create a sample on my side (using IE 11.116.18362.0), it looks that if we click the input field without doing anything, it will trigger the ng-touch event, if you try to change the value, it will trigger the ng-dirty event.